# Working with temporary columns (created on-the-fly) more efficiently in a dataframe

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Consider the following dataframe:

`df <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(1:10, 10, rep=TRUE)))`

If I want to divide each row by its sum (to make a probability distribution), I need to do something like this:

`df %>% mutate(rs = rowSums(.)) %>% mutate_each(funs(. / rs), -rs) %>% select(-rs)`

This *really* feels inefficient:

1. Create an `rs` column
2. Divide each of the values by their corresponding row `rowSums()`
3. Remove the temporarily created column to clean up the original dataframe.

When working with existing columns, it feels much more natural:

`df %>% summarise_each(funs(weighted.mean(., X1)), -X1)`

Using `dplyr`, would there a better way to work with temporary columns (created on-the-fly) than having to add and remove them after processing ?

I'm also interested in how `data.table` would handle such a task.

Comment: I think the problem is rows vs columns. With data frames the default assumption is that your columns can be and often are different classes, so it's unusual to apply a function to each row. That's more common with matrices, where all the entries are the same class and the `apply` function works easily on rows or columns. Here you're trying to treat each row as one class of thing. Transpose `t()` your `replicate` result before putting it in a data frame, and make distributions out of columns.

Comment: Why are you trying to force a `data.frame` or a `data.table` onto a matrix? As described your data doesn't make sense in a `data.frame/table`.

Comment: @Gregor - Your are right. But, this particular example was only intended to illustrate the temporary variable creation issue I was experiencing. Thanks for the feedback !

Comment: Yeah, I do understand that. I think you might need a different example... it's too hard to look past the obvious non-dplyr solution on this one. I would recommend a new example with a `group_by` so that it generalizes to typical dplyr use cases. This will also make it show it's need for dplyr/data.table in a more obvious way.

Comment: One idea would be to name all your temp variables in a way (e.g. `"varname.tmp"`, and then you could do a `select(!ends_with(".tmp"))` near the end of your pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment above I don't think that it makes sense to keep that data in either a `data.frame` or a `data.table`, but if you must, the following will do it without converting to a matrix and illustrates how to create a temporary variable in the `data.table` `j-expression`:

```
dt = as.data.table(df)

dt[, names(dt) := {sums = Reduce(`+`, .SD); lapply(.SD, '/', sums)}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not considering base `R` as well:

```
as.data.frame(as.matrix(df)/rowSums(df))
```

Or just with your `data.frame`:

```
df/rowSums(df)
```